# Is there any simple notation to determine the sum of applying a % to itself. ie $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {x^n}$ where 0 < x < 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I've come across this in finance/payroll.
eg. An employee accrues 8% of their worked hours as holiday time.
They also accrue more holiday time at this 8% rate when taking holiday time.

So after working for 100 hours, they are entitled to 8 hours of holiday.
If they take that 8 hours holiday now, they will accrue another 8% = 0.64 hours.
Again, if they continue to take that 0.64 hours, they will accrue another 0.0512 hours.
And so on.

I want to determine the total cost of those first 100 hours, factoring in their holiday time accrued (and the holiday time they will accrue during their holiday time).

Something like the following?
$$\text{hourly rate }\cdot \left(100 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty {100\cdot 0.08^n}\right)$$

But how do I easily calculate this in Excel?
Is there anything similar to e that represents this?

Yes I can easily approximate it, but I'm curious on the true solution.

Comment: Look up "geometric series"

Comment: See that if $$S(x)=1+x+x^2+\dots$$
Then,
$$S(x)-1=x\cdot S(x)\implies S(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key formula here is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac1{1-x}$$
This formula holds whenever $|x| < 1$. For example, if $x = 8\% = 0.08$, then this formula holds.

Based on the formula you've given, it seems like employees receive paid holiday. If an employee's hourly rate is $P$, and they receive a fraction $v$ of their worked hours as holiday time, then the total cost of $H$ worked hours is in fact
$$P \left( H + \sum_{n=1}^\infty Hv^n \right) = P \cdot \sum_{n=0}^\infty Hv^n = \frac{PH}{1-v}$$
This formula can be entered into Excel. In your case, we have $H = 100$ (i.e. you are considering 100 worked hours), and $v = 0.08$ (employees earn 8% of their worked hours as holiday time). This gives us
$$\text{Total Cost} = \frac{P \cdot 100}{1 - 0.08} = \frac{100P}{0.92} \approx 108.7P$$